# Angular 9 - refresh view ngOnChanges. Why do i need to use ChangeDetectorRef?

Tags: angular

In my scenario, I have a parent component that receives new data on button click. Child component receives these data by `@Input` field. In the child component event `ngOnChanges` is triggered. The value of `isLoaded` field is updated as expected. The question is: why my HTML condition `<div *ngIf="isLoaded">` requires `this.cd.detectChanges()` to notice that `isLoaded` flag has changed?

Parent component:

```js
@Component()
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  data: MyData;

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  updateWhenClickButton() {
    this.someService.getData(this.a, this.b, this.c).then(dataabc =>{
      this.data = new PurchasePriceBoxPlotData(this.a, this.b, dataabc);
    });
  }
}
```

Parent HTML content:

```html
<child-component [data]="data"></child-component>
```

Child component:

```js
@Component()
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input()
  data: MyData;
  
  isLoaded: boolean = false;

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.doSth();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.isLoaded = false;
    this.cd.detectChanges();
    this.doSth();
  }
  
  private doSth() {
    ....
    this.isLoaded = true;
  }
}
```

Child HTML:

```html
<div *ngIf="isLoaded">
    <custom-component [data]="data"></custom-component>
</div>
```

Edit

```
  public isLoaded$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
      this.isLoaded$.next(false);
      this.dosth();
      this.isLoaded$.next(true);
  }

<div *ngIf="isLoaded$ | async">
```

Comment: Can you give a stackblitz sample code?

Comment: You really shouldn’t have to normally - are you using onPush somewhere up the chain? Also - you are doing some strange things here. Why call ngOninit from onChanges and why are you assuming that when onChanges triggers loading is false?

Comment: @MikeOne
1. I'm not using onPush.
2. ngOninit just because I wanted to recreate the child component every time that new data appears. It's probably not the best idea because of the fact that oninit should be called once when the component is created. Maybe I should just update settings that are created during onInit instead of created them from scratch every time.
3. Just like I said in #2. this flag let me recreate the child component with updated data/settings.

Yeah, I know that it's probably not an optimal way but I'm just learning angular and looking for improvements.

Comment: Change detection happens at the end of the `ngOnChanges` by default, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Angular's change detection is a bit more complicated than it seems at first. Here is a good article that may help,

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html

Even with the default `ChangeDetectionStrategy` there are things you can do that do not get picked up by Angular's change detection and I think you ran into one of them.

I recommend that you use a [BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) rather than a simple boolean,

```
public BehaviorSubject<boolean> isLoaded$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
```

And then in your function,

```
ngOnChanges(): void {
  this.isLoaded$.next(false);
  ...
  this.isLoaded$.next(true);
}
```

And finally in your template,

```
<div *ngIf="isLoaded$ | async">
  <custom-component [data]="data"></custom-component>
</div>
```

You will not need to run `cd.detectChanges()` this way since the `BehaviorSubject` is streaming values directly to the template.

Also, as a side note, I wouldn't ever call `this.ngOnInit()`, that function is a hook meant to run at a specific point in the component's lifecycle and calling it manually could lead to all sorts of confusion down the road.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it.

Comment: I checked that and it seems that it still doesn't work. Added your changes to my comment. It load pages correctly at the first time but then on value change doesn't refresh view anymore.

Comment: The only thing that works is this.cd.detectChanges(); after this.isLoaded = false; I dont know why this.isLoaded = true; doesnt require separate detect changes